# HTML5 wrong input validation for email types + required

Tags: javascript, html

Having this HTML ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uu5hwwy/)):

```
<form>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Why is `hello@world` not being flagged as an invalid email address?

Tried using `pattern="/^\w+(?:\.\w+)*@\w+(?:\.\w+)+$/"` but not much luck either.

Comment: In general attempting to validate emails using regex is a bad idea. There are better ways to do it.

Comment: Did you get it work using the HTML5 `pattern` attribute?

Comment: @Cyzanfar, yes, it works - thanks!

Comment: Too many sites tell me that my email address is not valid _even though it is my **actual** email address_ that I use.  Almost everyone who uses a regex to validate email gets it wrong, by making it too restrictive. The fact is, _everything_ to the left of the `@` is valid, even another `@` if it's escaped correctly.  I suggest allowing the `input type="email"` to do its validation, then also check yourself there is a dot `.` somewhere.  You almost _always_ want to send an email to the address to verify it anyway, in case someone types a valid-looking _but wrong_ address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern instead:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

You can add a function that parses and validates the email string like so:

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) post.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://output.jsbin.com/ozeyag/19)

**HTML solution**
You can use the `pattern` attribute in HTML5 for validating emails:

```
<form>
        <input pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required /> 
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form>
```

Here is the source: [link](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/)

Comment: If using JS is an option, then this answer works fine. Thanks!

Comment: If it can't be solved with HTML only, then yes, it does.

Comment: Yes you can solve this problem using HTML. I've updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: If you use something simple like `[A-Za-z0-9(etc)]` you will exclude accented characters, like in `josé@losbaños.org` which are perfectly valid in emails and domains.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Every single regular expression in this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cyzanfar These fail nearly every single test case that isn't "foo@blah.com" or "foo+bar@blah.com" You're excluding non-Western languages. You're excluding IP addresses. You're excluding "foo=bar@blah.com". And, for that matter, you're excluding the EXTREMELY LONG list of TLDs longer than 6 characters.

Answer (score 6):

[From the HTML5 specifications :](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address)

> A valid e-mail address is a string that matches the email production of the following ABNF, the character set for which is Unicode. This ABNF implements the extensions described in RFC 1123. [ABNF] [RFC5322] [RFC1034] [RFC1123]
>
> email         = 1*( atext / "." ) "@" label *( "." label )
>
> label         = let-dig [ [ ldh-str ] let-dig ]  ; limited to a length of >63 characters by RFC 1034 section 3
>
> atext         = < as defined in RFC 5322 section 3.2.3 >
>
> let-dig       = < as defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5 >
>
> ldh-str       = < as defined in RFC 1034 section 3.5 >

Thus yes, `hello@world` is considered valid, because `*("." label)` does not force a `.` after the `@`

Comment: Thanks for this. Why wouldn't be a `.` necessary after the `@` in order to specify a valid email address? Valid within some intranets?

Comment: Because an email address is of the form : local@domain -- and a domain does not necessarily have a dot (see the example of an address such as contact@localhost). Further reading on hostnames constraints here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

Comment: And some TLDs have MX records on them, so presumably have email addresses at them.

Comment: +1 — This actually answers the OP's question _"Why is hello@world not being flagged as an invalid email address?"_ and bonus, it's _**correct!**_